# How do we make queues and commands buttons based of size N?

Tags: c++, queue

I am given a size N. From the size N, i need to generate some sort of char 1, char 2...... all the way to char N   and make a queue associated with that char. Example if i had N = 3.   Then it will generate a1, a2 ,a3  and this will be corresponding to queue 1 , queue 2 , queue 3....  My problem is whenever i use a "for loop" for char a[i] = ai. it won't work. at the bottom is a sample code

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void gen(int N)
{
    queue<int> qu[N];
    char a[];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
         a[i] = ai; // i want it to print a1, a2, a3 and 
                         //i want the queue associated with it
    }
}


int main()
{
     int N; 
     char b;
     cout << "Type a number for Size" << endl;
     cin  >> N;
     cout << "Type a command" << endl;
     cin >> b;
     gen(N);
     if( b == 'a1')
     {
          //does something
     }


}
```

Comment: this is absolutely unclear what you're asking

Comment: sorry i don't know how to phrase it really well i just need to keep generating new queues at the same time command for that queue

Comment: * Where are you entering the command?
* What are you storing in the queue?
* What is use of the queue?
* What is your concern with i = 0 ?

Comment: your typing the command in the shell (black box ) it cin << command which is a1  which stores  anything <int> inside it  but i need to generated more like a_N    and the concern with i = 0  was just what i tried

Comment: is that clear enough ? sorry :( i don't really know how to phrase it.

Comment: you're declaring `a` 3 times in your `gen` method. Does that compile?

Comment: o sorry that was just an explain i still don't know how to read A and 1 together :S